# exclude file from maven build

Tags: maven

I've a web application with file src/main/webapp/META-INF/context.xml which contains some configuration for testing database. On production server this file is in $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml and I'm testing with embedded tomcat so I don't want to package this file. I'd like to exclude this file from maven build. I tried following:

```
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>context.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

and also following:

```
<build>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>context.xml</exclude>
          </excludes>
        </resource>
      </resources>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

But the file still gets packaged in war and in build directory (eg. target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT/META-INF/context.xml). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18):

You can try using the `packagingExcludes` parameter

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <packagingExcludes>META-INF/context.xml</packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

To exclude a resource from build, the first snippet in the question looks fine, except that the absolute path of the `resource` `directory` should be specified.  For instance

```
<directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/META-INF</directory>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Is it somehow possible to completely exclude it from build? I mean also from build directory (eg. target/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT). If not I guess I can live with copying wars.

Comment: @woky. Updated answer in response to the additional query

Comment: @Raghuram: Unfortunately it doesn't work. (My Maven version: Apache Maven 3.0.2 (r1056850; 2011-01-09 01:58:10+0100)).

Comment: @Nishant: Sure. I originally wanted to completely exclude it form build. That's why I haven't clicked "Answered" yet.

Comment: Hi,i tried excluding files while building.But its not working.Any advise PLZ

Comment: @user170114. You should ask a new question specifying details of your problem and not use this thread. This will help people see it and answer it.

Comment: Works to keep it out of the war, but it still ends up in the target directory.

Answer (score 3):

The others have answered the main question but one other detail I noticed from your original attempted solution -

```
      <filtering>true</filtering>
```

In Maven, "resource filtering" doesn't mean what you probably think it means.  It's not about including/excluding resources but rather whether they should be processed to fill in embedded variable references.

See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Answer (score 0):

Recently I had a similar problem with persistence.xml. Try putting this into your POM:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>META-INF/context.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

If it does not help, try replace *maven-jar-plugin* with *maven-war-plugin*.