# Maven exclude file from final WAR

Tags: maven, war

I'm using Maven 3 to package a WAR file, and I cannot figure out how to exclude files in `src/main/webapp` from the final WAR generated. One of the directories in `src/main/webapp` is a git submodule, and I want to exclude files like README, docs/, etc. in that git submodule form going to my final WAR.

My initial attempt was to use the `maven-antrun-plugin` to delete the files. I tried the delete actions in `prepare-package` and `package`, but neither worked. Doing the deletes in `package` removed the files from my `target/<projname>/...`, but the final WAR still contains the files. Running maven with `-debug` shows that the files are deleted *after* the WAR file is generated. It's almost as if I want to do the deletes in between `prepare-package` and `package`.

My next attempts were to try to specify files to exclude from the WAR (some solutions linked below), but nothing seems to work. I might not be specifying the path to the unwanted files correctly, and I'm wondering if it has to do with the fact that my unwanted files are not in `src/main/resources`, but in `src/main/webapp`.

I've tried many solutions, but nothing seems to work. Each time I try something new, I do `mvn clean` and delete the `target` directory. The final generated WAR file always contains the unwanted files.

I feel like the answer to my problem exists on the SO and google searches I've come across, but nothing I've tried has worked exactly as I need. Below are some solutions I've tried.

- [exclude file from maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222539/exclude-file-from-maven-build)
- [In Maven how to exclude resources from the generated jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4113697/in-maven-how-to-exclude-resources-from-the-generated-jar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

since the files are inside the `webapp` folder I would guess the `maven-war-plugin` is the best point to start. the resource filtering with excludes points to `src/main/resources` and is not aware of the `webapp` folder.

So http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html

There is a parameter: `warSourceExcludes`: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html#warSourceExcludes

this should allow filtering the README files and so on.