# How to exclude an xml file in a maven jar dependency

Tags: java, maven

My project uses a jar that contains a file named **broker.xml**.
Also I have a second file with the same name **broker.xml** in the resource folder.
When I run the web application, I get an error "duplicates non mergeable resource broker.xml".

Is there a way to exclude the xml file inside the jar?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [exclude file from maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5222539/exclude-file-from-maven-build)

Comment: Are you trying to create a fat JAR or WAR?

Comment: I am creating a war file

Answer (score 1):

Try `TrueZIP` Maven Plugin, looks like  it suits your scenario

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>remove-a-file-in-sub-archive</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>remove</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>target/Samplewebapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/someJar.jar</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>broker.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

refer to below link for documentation

http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/

http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/remove-mojo.html

Also refer to below stackoverflow link (look at answer from @Andrea)
[Remove file from dependency jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2830837/remove-file-from-dependency-jar-using-maven)

Comment: Finally, I renamed the file in the jar to broker-2.xml. This is not the best solution but it works.